# Pillar coming out darker than other with the same material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I've made a building that looks like this at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, the two pillars in the middle of the building are a different color, even though they are both same object using one material. What's going on with my pillars, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check for duplicated vertices, clear split normals and/or make the normals consistent (Ctrl+N in edit mode)

Comment: How did you map the texture to the pillars? Because the texture looks different.